# WordPress Navwalker: Changing size of Navbar-Brand Clickable link?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Bit of an odd question. I can't seem to find a solution to it anywhere.

I'm using the Bootstrap navwalker on my WordPress site. When using the navbar-brand class to display and link my logo to the homepage, it seems you have to click in a very certain area of the logo (obviously not good from a usability point of view.) Does anyone know how to make this clickable area bigger?

My site: http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/

My code:

```html
 <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img class="logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu'              => 'primary',
                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'depth'             => 2,
                        'container'         => 'div',
                        'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                        'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                        'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
                ?>
            </div>    
        
     <div id='phone'>
     <img src='http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/wp-content/themes/BareTheme/images/telephone.png'><a href="callto:01600 890027">01600 890027</a>
     </div> 
</nav>
```

I do not believe my CSS is overriding anything as I haven't altered the width/height of any of the classes except the navbar toggle.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a strange situation you have going on here but I found that if you apply the following styles to the  and the  element the clickable area will span the entire logo.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye" style="min-width: 250px;">
<img id="logo" src="wp-content/themes/BareTheme/logo.png" alt="Paddle the Wye Logo" border="0" style="position: absolute;z-index: 2;"></a>
```

applying the min-width 250px to the link and position absolute and z-index to the logo will solve the issue